# How to replace the Ipyleaflet background map with a custom color?

Tags: leaflet, ipyleaflet

I'm able to remove the background map of ipyleaflet in a Jupyter Lab environment. This allows me to add (transparent) layers on a background, gray area. How can I change the color of that background?